# Cannot migrate tables in laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I made two new tables and tried migrating it to the database but it only migrates the first table and says already exists.

Comment: Share your migration code or check the table name in your migration

Comment: The table you trying to migrate already exist in the database, trying delete all tables and re-run migration.

Comment: you might have 2 migrations for creating one table. or you have manually created table already

Comment: If you are just starting then empty your database manually and then migrate. If you are updating the database with existing data then delete the tables from database and delete the entry of these two tables from `migration` table and then run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 2):

You need to rollback last migrations batch first:

```
php migrate:rollback
php migrate:migrate
```

Or to rollback all migrations and migrate again:

```
php migrate:refresh
```

This will work if you defined `down()` method in all migrations correctly.

Alternatively, in 5.5 you can run `fresh` command which will drop all tables and recreate them:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#running-migrations

Answer (score 0):

Have you added below line in AppServiceProvider.php?

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

in boot function